# mongosに接続できない

Tags: mongodb

MongoDBにてレプリカセット構成で環境を構築しています。
DBサーバ、configサーバは正常に動作しているのですが、
mongosサーバへ接続ができません。
※mongosサーバはconfigサーバとは接続できています。

```
[root@mongos user]# mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-08-29T07:50:01.514+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-08-29T07:50:01.514+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

mongosの設定ファイルは以下です。

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongos.log

# Where and how to store data.
#storage:
#  dbPath: /var/lib/mongos
#  journal:
#    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

sharding:
  configDB: rep/192.168.1.100:27019

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

解決方法など、わかる方がいらっしゃれば幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

レプリカセットだけであれば、mongosやconfigサーバは不要です。mongosやconfigサーバはシャードクラスタを使う場合に必要になるものです。

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/

> Config servers store the metadata for a sharded cluster.

---

接続の状態としては

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
```

ということなので、"mongo"を打っているのと同じマシンの27017番ポートにつなぎに行こうとしているものの、繋がっていない状態です。

mongoを打っているのと同じマシン上でmongosを起動されているでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
mongoを打っているのと同じマシン上でmongosを起動しています。

Comment: ps aux | grep mongoや、netstat -an | grep 27017の結果はどうでしょうか。mongosが起動していて、27017が開いていますでしょうか。また、mongosのロ‌​グ /var/log/mongodb/mongos.log には何か出力されているでしょうか。 mongosからシャードクラスタの各ノードに繋がらないなどの場合、mongosのプロセス自体は起動していても、コネクションを受け‌​付けない場合があるようです。